# Bootstrap 4 carousel - indicators click not working (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, html, bootstrap-4

I'm creating bootstrap 4 carousel on my app, and i have problem with indicators. Click on any of theme should navigate you to clicked photo, like this:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/carousel/

I don't know why it's not working, bootstrap 4 js is imported later that jquery so everything should work well.

Buttons next, prev are working but `data-slide-to` is not

my code:

```
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" *ngFor="let li of sliderImages; let i = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}"></li>

      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item"  *ngFor="let image of sliderImages; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
          <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="image">
        </div>

      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**EDIT**

When i paste code from bootstrap website with example carousel, indicators works... What's the problem with *ngFor loop? Structure is same...

Comment: Is there any errors in console?

Comment: No, everything is ok

Comment: Take a look at [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home), an Angular implementation of the Bootstrap components (which does not require jQuery). It has a [Carousel component](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/carousel/examples).

Comment: Yeah i used this, but i need fade animations between images :/ ng-bootstrap i think don't have this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah... I found solution... That's was so easy...

Attr data-target must have identical id, that's why that was not working...

```
<!-- here is the id -->
<div id="carouselExampleFade" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">

<!-- here's second id which must be equal to first one -->

        <li data-target="#carouselExampleFade" *ngFor="let li of sliderImages; let i = index" [attr.data-slide-to]="i" [ngClass]="{'active' : i == 0}"></li>

      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item"  *ngFor="let image of sliderImages; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'active': i == 0}">
          <img class="d-block w-100" [src]="image">
        </div>

      </div>
      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleFade" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>
```